# Mobile Broadband modem in Chromium OS

Tags: modem, 3g, chromium-os

I'd like to use my Internet-stick (T-mobile Web'n'Walk-Stick IV) in Chromium OS. But in Chromium OS there isn't any option to connect it.
What can I do?

```
chronos@localhost / $ modem status

Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0:
  GetStatus:
    state: 3
  Properties:
    Sim: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0
    ModemCapabilities: 4
    CurrentCapabilities: 4
    MaxBearers: 1
    MaxActiveBearers: 1
    Manufacturer: huawei
    Model: E176
    Revision: 11.104.14.01.55
    DeviceIdentifier: ad6c2116bb9b15623bb5e74de0dbf65b915ef170
    Device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6
    Drivers: option1
    Plugin: Huawei
    PrimaryPort: ttyUSB1
    EquipmentIdentifier: 355851023696989
    UnlockRequired: 1
    UnlockRetries: 3, 3, 10, 10
    State: 3
    StateFailedReason: 0
    AccessTechnologies: 0
    SignalQuality: 0, false
    PowerState: 3
    SupportedModes: 6
    AllowedModes: 6
    PreferredMode: 0
    SupportedBands: 0
    Bands: 0
  3GPP:
    Imei: 355851023696989
    RegistrationState: 4
    OperatorCode: 
    OperatorName: 
    EnabledFacilityLocks: 0
  CDMA:
  SIM /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/SIM/0:
    SimIdentifier: 89490200000608324351
    Imsi: 262015844047721
    OperatorIdentifier: 26201
    OperatorName: T-Mobile D

chronos@localhost / $
chronos@localhost / $ modem connect
successfully connected the modem
chronos@localhost / $ modem activate
error: modem has no CDMA capabilities
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version of Chromium OS offers the UMTS feature.
So the problem is solved now.